# Creating formulas linking cells in new worksheets created by the macro to summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a sheet and then in a separate summary sheet create formula’s that link to cells in this newly created copy. 
I am not having much success which may be an issue with how I’ve identified and named the new sheet or with how I’ve constructed the formulas (or both).

```
   Sub CopyCosting()
'
Dim currentNPD As String
Dim currentCOST As String
Dim currentCALC As String
Dim NewNPD As String
Dim NewCOST As String
Dim NewCALC As String


ActiveSheet.Select
currentNPD = ActiveSheet.Name
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
currentCOST = ActiveSheet.Name
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
currentCALC = ActiveSheet.Name

 Sheets(Array(currentNPD, currentCOST, currentCALC)).Copy After:= _
        Sheets("SUMMARY")
 Worksheets("SUMMARY").Select

 ActiveSheet.Next.Select
 NewNPD = ActiveSheet.Name

 ActiveSheet.Next.Select
 NewCOST = ActiveSheet.Name

 ActiveSheet.Next.Select
 NewCALC = ActiveSheet.Name


Worksheets("SUMMARY").Select


NextFree = Range("B9:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("A" & NextFree).EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B" & NextFree).Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=NewCOST!R[-39]C[-1]&"" (""&NewCOST!R[-35]C[3]&""x""&NewCOST!R[-37]C[3]&""g)"""

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(NewCOST!R[-40]C[5]>49,""AYR"",""Seasonal"")"

End Sub
```

The excel formula `#REFS` and in relation to the first concatenate formula I ask the macro to create it looks as below:

```
=[NewCOST]NewCOST!A2&" ("&[NewCOST]NewCOST!E6&"x"&[NewCOST]NewCOST!E4&"g)"
```

I expect the formula to return text in the following format when `R[-39]C[-1] = Cheese Cubes` and `R[-35]C[3] = 4 and R[-37]C[3] = 200`

`Cheese Cubes (4x200g)`

I hope this all makes sense! Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is best to use the workbook and worksheet functions instead of select:

```
Dim wb as Workbook, ws as worksheet, nws as worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("wsname")
set nws = wb.Worksheets("newws")'When you create new worksheet
```

Then you no longer need to use select when defining your range. Use:

```
ws.Range("...")
```

I would also try using the below for loop to interate through each cells formula, I would also write out the formula in excel and copy/paste in vba. Change the number with 'r':

```
For each r in Range("B" & NextFree)

'Formula here

Next r
```

Comment: Hi Blake, being new to this, I may not have understood completely.  I think I need the actual name written on the tab of the worksheet to use as “wsname”?
I want my macro users to be able to add more sheets to the workbook on an ad hoc basis.  They may add several sheets at once or one intermittently.  Most likely they will not even be naming the sheets they add.  
In trying to simplify the query I missed out that I’m concurrently copying 3 sheets at once to maintain the links in all the formulas.  I’ve edited the code above so you can see this if it helps to clarify.